# How to count the number of tables under a certain element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery is it possible to check if there is more than one table nested below a div with a certain class id?

EDIT: The class of the div not the table

Thanks Everyone.

When I do this:

```
alert($('.casmain > table').length);
```

I'm getting 0 back even though there are tables below.

The dic looks like that:

```
<div id="casmain" class="casmain">   
....
```

Thanks for the speedy response eveyone, much appreciated. I have acknowledged you all with +1 but unfortunately can only accept one answer, keep up the good work! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might do if you want tables at a first level inside the `div`

```
$('.outerDivClass > table.class').length;
```

If you want tables at all the nested levels:

```
$('.outerDivClass table.class').length;
```

Comment: should not we need to put '>' after outerDivClass .. means  $('.outerDivClass > table').length;??

Comment: @Dhaval I was wondering that OP needs elements at all the nested levels. thanks for pointing it out. BTW I'm a C++ guy :)

Comment: then also yu know this much about jquery .. it is gr8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
$('.myDivClassId table').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.class').find('table').length;
```

or

```
$('div.class > table').length;
```

Comment: you hav given my answer so +1

Comment: `$('div.class > table')` is wrong!, it just select the immediately table child of `div.class`

Comment: That's why I gave both possibilities, I'm not sure of what Joly want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do:

```
$(".divClass table.certainClass").length
```

Or for an ID (although, you should only use ID for **unique** elements so you shouldn't need to specify the `.divClass` part).

```
$(".divClass #certainID").length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#divid > table.className').length > 1) { };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('div.yourclass table').length
```

Or

```
$('div.yourclass').find(table).length
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance it's better that your div has an id instead of class attribute.

You can access to your information with :

```
if($('#myDiv table').length > 1)
{
    //...
}
```

If you want count only the tables in first level of DOM use :

```
if($('#myDiv > table').length > 1)
{
    //...
}
```